# iOS gamecenter - How to filter the fiends list to friends that also have the same app installed

Tags: ios, game-center

The return GKPlayer doesn't seem to contain any information.  I also didn't find anything so far in the GameKit guide or API documentation.   Do I really need a separate own server to track this information?

Comment: Can't do this with the current API, sorry

Comment: Thanks. I'm wondering what the use of gamecenter is at this point.  Also just found out I can't even pass a simple string between friends without my own server.  Back to the drawing board.  put your reply as an answer and i'll accept it. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do this with the current API. The list of API differences in iOS 6 doesn't help with this problem either. As for passing strings, you can transfer strings during a GKMatch or GKTurnBasedMatch session.

And to discuss the usefulness of Game Center: I think it's not a big deal that you can't see which friends have your game installed. This is mainly because when you try to invite a GC friend to a GKMatch/GKTurnbasedMatch, the invitation will be delivered regardless. If the app is not installed on the users phone, the invitation will direct the user to your app's page in the app store - better sales.

Comment: The list of 'playing' friends is useful if you send a string or 'gift' between players.  So for gamecenter I will need to track who has the game installed on my own server, store the gift code, support lookups, add worry about security.  The more I learn about gamecenter, the more limitations I find.  So I think my actual answer is going to be use facebook API.